# Analytic function that does not depend on $\bar z$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Given $$f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$$ which is analytic over a region $D$, I have to prove that it does not depend on $\bar z$ (the conjugate of $z$).

I've already tried replacing $x$ and $y$ by $\cfrac{z+\bar z}{2}$ and $\cfrac{z-\bar z}{2i}$.

What I get is a function $f$ which depends on $z$ and $\bar z$

I'm trying to relate the Cauchy-Riemann equations
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{}
\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\cfrac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\ 
\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\cfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
to $f(z)$ but I'm having some trouble.

Comment: Your statement is equivalent to "$f$ is analytic iff $\frac{df}{d\bar{z}}=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two-dimensional change of variables:
$$
x = \frac{z+\overline{z}}{2},\qquad y=\frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}
$$
Then
$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2},\qquad
\frac{\partial x}{\partial \overline{z}} = \frac{1}{2},
\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2i},\qquad
\frac{\partial y}{\partial \overline{z}} = \frac{-1}{2i},
$$
So, with the chain rule for partial derivatives:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \overline{z}} =
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\;\frac{\partial x}{\partial \overline{z}}
+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\;\frac{\partial y}{\partial \overline{z}}
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{1}{2i}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial \overline{z}} =
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\;\frac{\partial x}{\partial \overline{z}}
+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\;\frac{\partial y}{\partial \overline{z}}
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}-\frac{1}{2i}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
$$
Then, with $f = u+iv$ we get
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} = 
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)
+\frac{i}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)
\\=
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right) 
+ \frac{i}{2}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
+ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)
$$
Now if $u,v$ are real-valued, we get
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} = 0
\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{}
\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\cfrac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\ 
\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\cfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: The Cauchy-Riemann equations themselves are not enough, right? Because $z\bar{z}$ satisfies them at $z=0$ but it does depend on $\bar{z}$. You need them to hold on an open set. Which to me means that some form of the Cauchy integral formula must be employed (or series but that feels like cheating).